# ValidateAntiForgeryToken doesn't work with jQuery, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, antiforgerytoken

If I put `using (Html.BeginForm(...` it works. If I call the same action from jquery, it doesn't work. I put the token generated by `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` while sending the request. It shows error "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

What am I missing?

Below is my code:

Html:

```
<td id="@tdid">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRecord('@Id');" />
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
function deleteRecord(id) {
    var token = $("#td" + id).find('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(); //working

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAsync")',
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                RequestVerificationToken: token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                id: id
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data has been deleted.");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert("Error occurred: " + xhr.responseText);
                $("#msg").text(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteAsync(int id)
{            
    Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);    
    db.Items.Remove(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json("Record deleted", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```